# Getting difference of two counts in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm doing some QA in Netezza and I need to compare the counts from two separate SQL statements. This is the SQL that I am currently using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RECORD_COUNT  
FROM db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE  A
LEFT JOIN (select distinct CURRENTLY_OPTED_IN_FL,mid_key from db..F_EMAIL) B
ON A.MID_KEY=B.MID_KEY
MINUS
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE  A
```

However, it seems like MINUS doesn't work like that. When the counts match, instead of returning 0, this will return null for Record_count.  I basically the record count to be computed as:

```
record_count=count1-count2
```

So it is 0 if the counts are equal or the difference otherwise. What is the correct SQL for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RECORD_COUNT  
FROM db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE  A
LEFT JOIN (select distinct CURRENTLY_OPTED_IN_FL,mid_key from db..F_EMAIL) B
ON A.MID_KEY=B.MID_KEY
)  -
(
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE  A
) TotalCount
```

Oracle's `MINUS` ([`EXCEPT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) in SQL Server) is a whole different animal :)

If you understand `UNION` and then think sets, you will understand `MINUS` / `EXCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

`MINUS` is set difference, not for arithmetic operations.

You could do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM   db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE A) AS Val
FROM   db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE A
       LEFT JOIN (select distinct CURRENTLY_OPTED_IN_FL,
                                  mid_key
                  from   db..F_EMAIL) B
         ON A.MID_KEY = B.MID_KEY
```

Or another option

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT A.PrimaryKey) AS Val
FROM   db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE A
       LEFT JOIN (select distinct CURRENTLY_OPTED_IN_FL,
                                  mid_key
                  from   db..F_EMAIL) B
         ON A.MID_KEY = B.MID_KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you are looking for

```
    SELECT COUNT(distinct(CURRENTLY_OPTED_IN_FL + F_EMAIL.MID_KEY)) - count(distinct(EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE.MID_KEY))
    FROM EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN F_EMAIL
      ON JOIN F_EMAIL.MID_KEY = EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE.MID_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle db, extending the answer by Adriano Carneiro above, should do the trick:

```
SELECT (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS RECORD_COUNT  
FROM db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE  A
LEFT JOIN (select distinct CURRENTLY_OPTED_IN_FL,mid_key from db..F_EMAIL) B
ON A.MID_KEY=B.MID_KEY
)
-
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM db..EXT_ACXIOM_WUL_FILE  A)
CustomVarName from DUAL;
```

ps
MINUS is just the standard operation for Sets in Math